# how can I cancel an Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cancellation

In phonegap how to cancel an ajax request in program, I would like to set cancel button for control the request when it's too slow

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function(m) {
        alert( "success");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

hi it's similar as [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery?lq=1),anyway This can help you

```
 var ab = $.ajax({  type: "GET",  url: url,  success: function(m)  {    alert( "success");  } });

//kill the request
ab.abort()
```

Answer (score 6):

Store the promise interface returned from ajax request in a `global` `variable` and `abort` it on cancel click

```
var result = $.ajax({  type: "GET",  url: url,  success: function(m)  {    alert( "success");  } });


$('#cancel').click(function() {
    result.abort();
});
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can store the result in `global` variable and `abort` the request on a button call

Comment: You're not storing the result, you're storing the returned deferred promise, and it exposes the native XMLHttpRequest which has an abort method.

Answer (score 2):

```
var request= $.ajax({  type: "GET",  url: url,  success: function(m)  {    alert( "success");  } });


$('#cancel').click(function() {
    request.abort();
});
```

this will abort the request from the client(browser) side but note : if the server has already received the request, it may continue processing the request (depending on the platform of the server) even though the browser is no longer listening for a response. There is no reliable way to make the web server stop processing a request that is in progress.

Comment: Wait, how is this different than already posted answer??? EDIT: your words about server not handling it is interresting thought

Comment: I just explained. nothing more than that. OP should know what actually is going to happen not only how it can be achieved.

Comment: Ya, edited my previous comment, i'm quite agree here!

Comment: I did not mention that kind of words....:)